# Cannot find a functor instance for Tuple2K

Tags: scala, functor, scala-cats, comonad

I have a toy DSL

```
case class Logging[A](msg: String, action: A)
case class Persist[A](msg: String, action: A)
type Effect[A] = EitherK[Logging, Persist, A]
```

that I want to pair with an equally toy interpreter

```
case class CoLogging[A](run: String => A)
case class CoPersist[A](run: String => A)
type Interp[A] = Tuple2K[CoLogging, CoPersist, A]
```

Here is an program example:

```
def prog(implicit L: Logs[Effect], P: Persists[Effect]): Free[Effect, Unit] =
  P.store("bar") >> L.log("foo")
```

and here is the interpreter:

```
def interpretEffect(implicit CL: CoLogs[IO], CP: CoPersists[IO]): Cofree[Interp, IO[Unit]] = 
  Cofree.unfold(IO.pure(())) { a: IO[Unit] => Tuple2K(CoLogging(CL.coLog(a)), CoPersist(CP.coPersist(a))) }
```

I've paid due diligence and defined functors as well as injection implicits. The compiler complains that it cannot find an instance `cats.Functor[[A]cats.data.Tuple2K[example.CoLogging,example.CoPersist,A]]`, even though I am importing `cats.data.Tuple2K._` [where the instance is implicitly defined](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Tuple2K.scala#L120-L131).

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, it must be something stupid. Do you have any idea? All the code can be seen [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/regiskuckaertz/334fa76da70dbd4b7d13a58e9d3ee24e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The compiler complains that it cannot find an instance
>   `cats.Functor[[A]cats.data.Tuple2K[example.CoLogging,example.CoPersist,A]]`,
>   even though I am importing `cats.data.Tuple2K._` [where the instance is implicitly defined](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Tuple2K.scala#L120-L131).

`Functor[Tuple2K[F, G, ?]]` is defined via `Tuple2KInstances8#catsDataFunctorForTuple2K` if `Functor[F]` and `Functor[G]` were defined. The thing is that `Functor[CoLogging]` and `Functor[CoPersist]` weren't.

Add

```
object CoLogging {
  implicit val coLoggingFunctor: Functor[CoLogging] = new Functor[CoLogging] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: CoLogging[A])(f: A => B): CoLogging[B] = CoLogging(fa.run andThen f)
  }
}
```

and

```
object CoPersist {
  implicit val coPersistFunctor: Functor[CoPersist] = new Functor[CoPersist] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: CoPersist[A])(f: A => B): CoPersist[B] = CoPersist(fa.run andThen f)
  }
}
```

and everything should compile.

The thing is the order of implicits. Move object `functors` to the beginning and everything should compile.

Comment: I knew this, but they _are_ defined [here](https://gist.github.com/regiskuckaertz/334fa76da70dbd4b7d13a58e9d3ee24e#file-cofree-scala-L67-L73)

Comment: @RegisKuckaertz OK, then the thing is the order of implicits. Move object `functors` to the beginning and everything should compile.

Comment: what the...?? it worked. This is complete nonsense. this language is so weak. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

For using cats functors in your code, you need to try to add settings in your build.sbt file.

```
scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"
```

Maybe ths will hepls you. This is limitation of scala compiler https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712